# "ERROR! 'aws_s3' is not a valid attribute for a Play" when running aws_s3 playbook

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ansible

I have a playbook that I am testing that should create an s3 bucket if one doesn't already exist, and if it does exist do nothing. I'm trying to test it but when I do I get the error

```
'ERROR! 'aws_s3' is not a valid attribute for a Play'.
```

I have all the requirements specified on the docs installed (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/aws_s3_module.html), so why is this happening?

```
- name: Check s3 bucket for test_bucket exists
  aws_s3:
    bucket: test-bucket
    mode: geturl
    ignore_nonexistent_bucket: yes
    region: {{ region }}
  register: asset_url

- name: Create s3 bucket for test_bucket library
  aws_s3:
    bucket: test-bucket
    mode: create
    region: {{ region }}
  when: asset_url is defined
```

I am testing as I'm unsure if this will work at all - but then ran into another problem of not being able to run the playbook.

Comment: Firstly all { region } all variable replacement in ansible happends through {{ region }} syntax. Can you please re run the playbook with -vvv(verbose) ?

Comment: Edited the question to use proper syntax, in the actual playbook I've specified the region

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, I was confused between 'roles' and 'playbooks', and was trying to run a role as a playbook. What I should have done is had a playbook that calls this role